# Open Windows 10 Windows Explorer to My Documents ("User Files") Specific Folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, folder-redirection

How do I open a subfolder in the My Documents ("User Files") instead of the default under My computer? I explicitly do *not* want Windows Explorer to expand to the folder via My Computer. I intend to create a shortcut to whatever command is necessary so I don't have to manually open this folder every time I boot my computer.

For those paying attention to create a custom My Documents folder (on a different drive) you can modify the following command:

`Mklink /J "C:\Users\John\JAB Creations" "D:\My Documents\JAB Creations"`

[image: My Documents Subfolder]

Answer (score 0):

This will have to be loaded in a batch file because of the space in the folder though it works from the *Run* window.

`shell:UsersFilesFolder\JAB Creations`

To run this in a batch program (e.g. to put in your User's Startup folder in the Start Menu) use the following:

`start %windir%\explorer.exe shell:UsersFilesFolder\JAB Creations`